# Meaning of unwind_code operation 6

Tags: windows, seh

In windows SEH data, there exists a facility to define for a given `RUNTIME_FUNCTION` some pseudo-operations which describe its effect on the stack.  They are defined here in the documentation for `UNWIND_CODE`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exception-handling-x64?view=msvc-170

However, Microsoft have only documented version 1!  In some things that ship with windows (such as notepad), the given version for the exception handling data is 2.  It looks to me as though they are very similar (see also http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=31650579), except that there is a mysterious and very common operation code 6, which is not defined in the version 1 documentation.

From my admittedly small sample, it appears that the op info is always 0 or 1, and the operation appears to consume only one slot in the unwind op data.

It seems that in ReactOS, it is taken to mean UWOP_SAVE_XMM (see http://doxygen.reactos.org/d4/d85/rtl_2amd64_2unwind_8c_a552b9ed5f66cb1a0015f7523bfce2eb9.html#a552b9ed5f66cb1a0015f7523bfce2eb9).  This is an unlikely meaning for it in this case (the "version 2" case), since the following slots contain valid unwind operations rather than sane memory offsets.

What is the meaning of unwind operation 6?

Comment: Do you mind sharing why you need this information? I am curious.

Comment: This data is the only way to get a reliable stack trace (without symbols at least) from a crashed process in memory in 64-bit windows.  Many of the codes describe the stack displacement of a function.